# Laravel Eager Loading with partition table

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, partition

```
public function record_2020_11(){
    $deviceRecords = new DeviceRecord();
    $deviceRecords->setSuffix(self::$suffix);

    return $this->newHasMany($deviceRecords->newQuery(), $this, 'device_id', 'id');
}

public function record_2020_12(){
    $deviceRecords = new DeviceRecord();
    $deviceRecords->setSuffix(self::$suffix);

    return $this->newHasMany($deviceRecords->newQuery(), $this, 'device_id', 'id');
}

public function hasManyDeviceRecords(array $suffixes)
{
    $device = null;
    foreach ($suffixes as $suffix) {
        self::$suffix = $suffix;
        $device = $this->with('record_'.$suffix);
    }
    return $device;
}
```

I want to get relation like

$devices = (new Device)->hasManyDeviceRecords(['2020_11','2020_12'])->get()->toArray();

**The code above is what I am trying**  It's failed.

Q1: I want to get arrays below

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [record_2020_11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [device_id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [device_id] => 1
                      
                    )
            )
        [record_2020_12] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [device_id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [device_id] => 1
                      
                    )
            )
    )
```

Q2:I don't want the function name has suffix like 2020_11 2020_12;

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwYjg.png)

Comment: It seems that you want DeviceRecords grouped by month. You can have a `HasMany` relation defined on Device like Device hasMany DeviceRecords and then query the relationship and group by month. I don't think there's need to create functions for different months it's not scalable and probably impractical. If you can post your migrations I can help with probable relations and queries

Comment: That is just the final format of the data which you can get by using Collection methods like all(). What I'm trying to point out is that defining methods for month wise grouping of data is not practical or scalable. You can get the data grouped month wise using groupBy on collection. Laravel relation will make querying data easy and it seems very logical based on what you have Device hasMany DeviceRecords

Comment: @Donkarnash
Do you know partition table relation? 
How did you get 2020_11 2020_12 records belongs to device_id = 1
I want to get array like I showing in Question1
It's not a groupBy problem.

Comment: Okay probably I don't quite understand your issue. I wasn't thinking in terms of partition table - my bad